# PyAutoGUI for loop unable to loop through

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm trying to loop through a list of image for

```
pyautogui.locateOnScreen()
```

Here is my approach

```
vnc2 = r"D:\directory\of\image\vnc_2.png"
vnc3 = r"D:\directory\of\image\vnc_3.png"
vnc4 = r"D:\directory\of\image\vnc_4.png"
vnc_list = [vnc2 , vnc3, vnc4]

        for step in vnc_list :
            x,y = pa.locateOnScreen(step)
            pa.click(x,y)
            time.sleep(2)
```

The trace back as below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "d:\Self learn\python automation\MMVNA_auto.py", line 101, in automation
    x,y = pa.locateCenterOnScreen(step)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Is it not right to loop through ? or did i miss out something important ？

---

Updates

Beginners mistake
Here is my code before the `for` loop

```
        x,y = pa.locateCenterOnScreen(vnc1)
        pa.click(x,y) 
        pa.typewrite("192.168.7.2")
        pa.press("enter")
        for step in vnc_list :
            x,y = pa.locateCenterOnScreen(step)
            pa.click(x,y)
            time.sleep(2)
```

i left out the  `time.sleep(5)` after `pa.press("enter")`

Comment: What it's telling you is that `locateOnScreen` returned `None`, meaning that the image was not found.  You aren't checking for any error conditions here.

Comment: Took me a while to find out i didn't delay before the loop started, silly mistake

Comment: If you solved this, please write down the answer and mark you own question answered. Helps people with similar errors in the future.